# remote rviz does not set pose or goal

Tags: ros, rviz, position, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing navigation stack on my robot using rviz remotely. Rviz shows all the data from the robot without errors. But when I try to set robot position or goal position nothing happens. If I use rviz on the robot it works.
Some weeks ago, I used rviz remotely without problems but now I cannot set position or goal despite the other data are displayed (laser, map, inflated obstacles, odometry).
Any explanation/solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47873/remote-rviz-does-not-set-pose-or-goal/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably a network problem. I guess you can ping your robot from the computer running rviz but not the other way around. In that case, rviz can connect to topics published on the robot, but the robot cannot connect to topics on your PC. Have a look at the [network setup page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2